# Why does my canvas animate MUCH slower than a simple ImageView + matrix?

Tags: android, animation, android-asynctask, android-canvas

I am implementing a panorama viewer. I did it with an ImageView, moving the image with its Matrix in an AsyncTask (`foto` is the ImageView, `m` is a Matrix):

```
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        if (values[0] == 0) {
            m.setScale(scale, scale);
            m.postTranslate(values[1], 0);
            foto.setImageMatrix(m);
        }
    }
```

It works pretty well, except that the movement is not very smooth (smooth = constant velocity, in particular, no "jumps" and no "stops").

Looking for a solution, I read in the documentation about Canvas:

*Option "b," drawing to a Canvas, is better when your application needs to regularly re-draw itself. Applications such as video games should be drawing to the Canvas on its own.*

Looks like this is exactly what I need!!  So I did the following:

First, I created a `scaleBitmap`, the image scaled to fit the window in height (this is to avoid maaaany rescales), and a screen-sized bitmap `fitBitmap`. Then, I create two equal screen-sized rectangles, `destRect` and `srcRect`. Now, the new `onProgressUpdate()` AsyncTask method is:

```
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        if (values[0] == 0) {
            srcRect.offset(-1, 0);
            canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, srcRect, destRect, null);
            foto.setImageBitmap(fitBitmap);
        }
    }
```

And this also works. But it is much, MUCH slower than before!! Not only that, it 'jumps' lots of frames, unless I set the speed to be very low. Horrible! But Canvas is good to speed up animation, according to the documentation. So I am doing something terribly wrong.

Could you please tell me which is my mistake, or how to better implement this?

Thanks!!

**EDIT**

Based on (what I understood about) @aragaer suggestion, I tried the following, without luck (still slow and jumpy):

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        if (values[0] == 0) {
            m.setScale(scale, scale);
            m.postTranslate(values[1], 0);
            canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, m, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(fitBitmap, 0, 0, null);
            foto.invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Tried also commenting/uncommenting either/both last two lines in the method without luck. Without the last, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

It invalidates the whole view in second case. That's why.

You shouldn't use `setImageView` at all - override `onDraw` and draw the bitmap directly. This will be faster.

The correct way to do it looks like this:

- You create your own bitmap, same size as the view you are going to use.
- You create a canvas and set it to draw into that bitmap.
- When you need something drawn, you draw stuff into that canvas. Knowing the exact changed rectangle you invalidate that exactly rectangle of your view. `onDraw` gets called where you are drawing your cache bitmap into the canvas provided.

Here's a link to a widget that draws lines as user moves his finger over surface: [link](https://github.com/aragaer/reminder_android/blob/master/src/com/aragaer/reminder/DrawView.java). It's a bit more complex since I use two bitmaps, one for internal representation, another for what's shown to user. Ignore that and look at how I use the `cache` bitmap.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your answer. I added `foto.invalidate();` to the `onProgressUpdate` method, without any luck. Is there a tweak to use what I did? Could you be a more specific? Thanks!

Comment: when you call `setImageBitmap()` the whole image is invalidated and redrawn from scratch. When you change matrix, only the changed rectangle is redrawn. Updated my answer.

Comment: MMmmm... My last version does not call `foto.setImageBitmap(fitBitmap)`, but `foto.invalidate()`... with the same problem (of course). But if I don't put either (i.e, only 3 lines inside `onProgressUpdate() {...}`), nothing happens, the screen is not updated at all (why??). You wrote: *override onDraw and draw the bitmap directly*, but I am already *drawing the bitmap directly* with `canvas.drawBitmap...` Maybe this is somehow wrong, I should reuse via a matrix the part of `fitBitmap` already drawn, or something else? As you realize, this newbie is a bit lost... :o) Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, you draw your own bitmap, but you still have to draw that bitmap to the screen. This is done in `onDraw` method of your view. You are given new canvas and you have to draw your bitmap onto that canvas like this: `canvas.drawBitmap(fitBitmap, 0, 0, null)`

Comment: So two `canvas.drawBitmap()` are needed? Tried adding the second without luck (please see the EDIT at the end of the original post).

Comment: Ok, I will take a look at this carefully and report later. Thanks a lot for your patience!

Comment: I don't see how your technique can be useful for what I need to do. As I wrote, I am doing a *panorama viewer*. That is, the *whole* image scrolls, and not a single pixel stays the same from one frame to the next. However, maybe I can implement some mix: translate the image to the left one pixel, and after that only draw the last column at the right. Probably this would not be faster, though, since I am already using the matrix. Well, thanks anyway!

Comment: You can have cache larger than the whole view. Keep some x and y coordinates and then draw only the required rectangle from cache into canvas in onDraw event.